# unite 2 strings from array Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop

I want to unite 2 strings from an array extracted from a text file:

```
for n in arrayhere:
    for i in arrayhere:
        newvariable = n+i
```

I also tried `x.split()` in both for loops and `str(n+i)`.

When I print `newvariable` or write it on the text file, variables are printed or written not in the same line.

Comment: Do you have new line characters at the end of each element in your list? Try printing the list and see what it looks like. Can you also show me the code that you're using to extract the data from the text file?

Comment: if you print `n` is it on the same line?

Comment: if you have newline characters in either string you could use `strip('\n')`

Comment: ['\n',, 'villero\n', '99\n', '00\n', '01\n', '02\n', '03\n', '05\n', '1999\n', '2000\n', '2001\n', '2002\n', '2003\n', '2004\n', '2005\n', '2010\n', '2011\n', '2012\n', '2013\n', '2014\n', '2015\n', '2016\n', '8\n', '9\n', '10\n', '11\n', '12\n', '13\n', '14\n', '15\n', '16\n']

Comment: Thanks, now see the fail. But how can i solve it? I tried before "if i == \n" but i didnt realise other data ending.

Comment: file = open('file.txt','r')

Comment: arrayhere = file.readlines()

Comment: @Alejandro Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code prior to looping through the elements in your list (they're not called arrays in python, but i'll refer to the list as `arrayhere` just like you did so you can substitute the code easily):

```
arrayhere = [x.strip('\n') for x in arrayhere]
```

This will strip the new line characters from the elements in your list. The `\n` at the end of each element are what's causing your `newvariable = n + i` to print on separate lines.

This would be an ideal way to read your text file into the list:

```
with open(/path/to/file) as f:
    arrayhere = f.readlines()
arrayhere = [x.strip('\n') for x in arrayhere]
```

... and then you can do as you were previously doing:

```
for n in arrayhere:
    for i in arrayhere:
        newvariable = n + i
```